# How to debug / step through an android application without using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adt

Lately i've had issues with ADT14/15 and their eclipse integration for debugging/building/cleaning android apps.  However using ant and a build.xml file is working flawlessly.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how i might control the eclipse debugger from ant?  Ideally i'd like to add a custom ant task that i can launch from within eclipse (ant build) that would initiate a debug session between eclipse and adb so i can step through the code using eclipse without relying on adt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that even though ADT 14/15/16 are unable to build and debug my project because of various errors like.. unable to find blah.apk etc.  If you use ant to build just make sure you build a debug version and install it to your phone.  Then run DDMS from within eclipse.  Select your process and click the green bug icon.  This will enable debugging and allow step thru of your code in eclipse.